# Как просмотреть значение переменной в cshtml при отладке Visual Studio?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, отладка, visual-studio-2017

При наведении на name не показывает её значение.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#submit').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var name = $('#input_price').val();
        name = encodeURIComponent(name);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Отладка JavaScript-кода внутри `cshtml`-страницы в среде разработки Visual Studio, насколько мне известно, недоступна. Вы можете поставить *Breakpoint* на элемент Razor-разметки - там точка останова сработает. И чтобы увидеть значение переменной - Вам необходимо, чтобы Ваш код был активен именно в том месте, где Вы этого хотите. Иными словами, если хотите увидеть в JavaScript-коде, нужно чтобы он в данный момент выполнялся и там была к примеру точка останова.

Для отладки JavaScript-кода на странице, лично я пользуюсь разными подходами. Первые два подхода - с использованием браузера.

### 1. Использование ключевого слова `debugger`

Пишем в JavaScript-коде вот такую строку:

```
debugger;
var name = $('#input_price').val();
```

Пишем эту строку там, где хотим остановиться.

> Выражение [`debugger`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/debugger) открывает доступ к любому доступному в конкретном
>   окружении отладочному функционалу, например к установке точек останова
>   (т.н. брейкпоинтов).

Чтобы брейкпоинт сработал (выполнилась приостановка) - нужно открыть исходный код текущей страницы в браузере (к примеру в *Google Chrome* это пункт <kbd>Просмотреть код</kbd>)

### 2. Использование `console.log`

Использовать можно в качестве отладочной информации и для дальнейшей инспекции и отладки кода. Довольно-таки банальный способ, но очень действенный. К примеру, я хочу посмотреть, что было в переменной, по Вашему коду:

```
var name = $('#input_price').val();
console.log(name);
```

Метод [`console.log`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Console/log) - выводит сообщения в веб-консоль. На подобии предыдущего пункта открываем <kbd>Просмотреть код</kbd>, идем на вкладку <kbd>Console</kbd> - и видим, что у нас было в переменной `name`. Просто и действенно. Ну и наконец перейдем к тому, что Вам должно помочь.

### 3. Перенос JavaScript-кода из `.cshtml` в отдельный файл `.js`

Как я сказал в начале: отлаживать `Razor` на странице внутри Visual Studio - пожалуйста, но не JavaScript. Выносим функционал JavaScript-кода в отдельный файл (к примеру `MyCshtml.js`), помещаем его в папку (`Scripts` к примеру), где-то рядышком, и подключаем на странице как-то так:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/MyCshtml.js"></script>
```

После этой не хитрой манипуляции точки останова в среде разработки должны заработать и Вы сможете увидеть, что у Вас находится в той или иной переменной в Вашем JavaScript-коде в момент отладки определенного кода. Причем сайт нужно открывать в браузере Internet Explorer, именно он дружит с Visual Studio, так как оба продукта от Microsoft.

---

### 4. Visual Studio 2017 в паре с Internet Explorer 11 и `debugger`

Пожалуй, самый банальный способ, как показала практика рассуждений с @Grundy - это использование ключевого слова `debugger` внутри JavaScript-кода `cshtml`-страницы.

- Выбираем браузер по умолчанию для открытия нашего сайта *Internet
  Explorer*.
- Открываем сайт в IE и переходим в <kbd>Настройки</kbd> ->
  <kbd>Свойства браузера</kbd> - вкладка <kbd>Дополнительно</kbd> -
  раздел <kbd>Обзор</kbd> , убираем галочку напротив строки:
  <kbd>Отключить отладку сценариев (Internet Explorer)</kbd>, жмем
  <kbd>Применить</kbd>, а затем <kbd>ОК</kbd>

После этого точки остановки в месте ключевого слова `debugger` срабатывают внутри среды разработки Visual Studio 2017.

Ссылка на источник по настройке VS и IE: [How to debug (only) JavaScript in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15568473/5275890).

Проверил на VS2017 в паре с IE11 в операционной системе Windows 10.

Comment: при использовании IE, и возможно EDGE, точки остановки в яваскрипте вываливаются в студийный отладчик

Comment: @Grundy, не совсем понял. Точки остановки, которые я в среде разработки поставил? Поясните пожалуйста.

Comment: Да, студия позволяет ставить точки остановки на строках яваскрипт кода. При запуске отладки проекта в IE - при достижения точки остановки управление переходит в студию, и в студийном отладчике видны все нужные переменные

Comment: @Grundy, хм... странно, я не знал про это, но в данный момент открыл сайт на своей локальной машине, присоединился к процессу сайта, развернутый в IIS, в IE, перешел на страницу, в cshtml которой я поставил брэйк в блоке JS и ничего не произошло. У меня VS2017, Windows10, IIS, IE11

Comment: [How to debug (only) JavaScript in Visual Studio?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15568245/2881286)

Comment: @Grundy, из ответа: *you can set breakpoints in your JS file* как я и говорил в третьем пункте.

Comment: У меня точки и в cshtml нормально ставятся на js код

Comment: @Grundy, раньше присоединялся к процессу через `Attach to Process...`, теперь просто сайт запускаю из VS как в том ответе. В итоге тоже не срабатывают брэйки студийные. VS2015 я снес, не смогу проверить в ней. Может дело в IE11  и новой 17-студии?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55742/discussion-between-grundy-and-denis-bubnov).

Comment: Использую вариант 3 . Breakpoint не работает.No symbols have been loaded for this document

Comment: @codename0082016, вот посмотрите мой ответ: [The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36447000/5275890)

Comment: Denis Bubnov не помогло

Comment: @codename0082016, там в ответе есть ссылка на источник, перейдя по ней наткнетесь на другие ответы. Просто были моменты, когда именно эти манипуляции не помогали. Смотрели на другие ответы? Брэйкпоинт в `.js` файле не срабатывает? А в других срабатывает? Как ведете отладку? На локальной машине, на сервере? Среда IDE под админом запущена? Больше деталей, пока размытое представление о Вашей огтладке

Comment: @codename0082016, простите, я забыл написать в ответе, что обязательно нужно в браузере IE открывать сайт :( там точно сработает брэйкпоинт.

Comment: Можно просто точку останова поставить в Chrome

Comment: @Alex78191, можно, но вопрос был в том, чтобы сделать это при отладке в Visual Studio, а не в браузере.

Comment: Значит никак :-(